# Как получить одинаковое расстояние между блоками?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы расстояние между блоками с параметрами (этаж, высота потолков итд) было одинаковым, как в макете? Я пытался сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении экрана расстояние не уменьшалось, но кроме как через calc выставить что-то похожее, что задано на макете- не получилось. Ну может еще какие-то мелкие косяки заметите, буду только рад вашим конструктивным замечаниям.

Макет https://www.figma.com/file/9srXB2Gsy5e7dpmcEmC2or/...

Сам сайт tempessj.beget.tech

Код jsfiddle.net/h0tw12dL/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для данной сетки я бы советовал использовать **[Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)**:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  grid-gap: 2em 3em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid__title,
.grid__des {
  display: block;
}

.grid__title {
  color: gray;
}

.grid__des {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Этаж</span>
    <span class="grid__des">3 из 19</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Высота</span>
    <span class="grid__des">потолков 3,2 м</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Отделка</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Предчистовая</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Общая</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Площадь 32,24 м2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Жилая</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Площадь 22,24 м2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Площадь</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Кухни 14,24 м2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

А для второго варианта достаточно изменить `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
  grid-gap: 2em 3em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid__title,
.grid__des {
  display: block;
}

.grid__title {
  color: gray;
}

.grid__des {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Этаж</span>
    <span class="grid__des">3 из 19</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Высота</span>
    <span class="grid__des">потолков 3,2 м</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Отделка</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Предчистовая</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Общая</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Площадь 32,24 м2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Жилая</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Площадь 22,24 м2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="grid__item">
    <span class="grid__title">Площадь</span>
    <span class="grid__des">Кухни 14,24 м2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Хорошая штука грид, но я не увидел существенного отличия от моего кода с флексами

Comment: @Ziora, дополнил

Comment: получилось, НО на 920 пикселях не получается сохранить пропорции отступов между блоками и до серой линии. на разрешении до 1000 пикселей я выставил grid-gap: 0em 4em, чтобы хоть немного приблизиться к пропорциям,но...                                                                                                           Вот что у меня получилось http://tempessj.beget.tech/ и вот как надо https://www.figma.com/file/9srXB2Gsy5e7dpmcEmC2or/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0?node-id=3%3A97